# Cannot figure out how to wait for text in input value

Tags: typescript, playwright

Scenario:
I need to wait for some specific text to load on the page, the issue im experiencing is that the text is the value of an input box and this value is the last thing on the page to load/appear.

I was wondering if there was some way to tell playwright:

wait for the text value in this input box to = "text input value"

I've used `await this.page.locator('my locator').inputValue();` but I noticed that the value can sometimes return blank when the page takes a little longer to load so i need to specifically wait for it before continuing.

at the moment Im waiting for a specific Api request to complete which works for now, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to check the value on the document's `load` event?

Comment: i have tried `await this.page.waitForLoadState("networkidle",{timeout:10000});` and 
`await this.page.waitForLoadState("load",{timeout:10000});` and `domcontentloaded` with no success.  Would this be what you were referring to @ArshiaMoghaddam

Comment: Use **auto- retrying assertions**. See this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77253327

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about you use the [locator assertions to have value](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value) with custom timeout. Something like:

```js
const locator = page.locator('my locator')
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('your value', {timeout: 20000})
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was looking for `toHaveValue` on the expect, I can't believe I didnt notice that thank you the tests are all passing now.

Comment: For others: If it’s not an input field, use `toHaveText`

Comment: How to use for Java?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('text=Log in',{timeout:25000})
```

adapt the selector, you can use text or css or xpath. And you can change timeout value to one that suits you, it is in mili seconds.

Comment: I've also tried getting page.waitForSelector to work as well by writing out

`await this.page.waitForSelector('text="/Employee/Record"');` 

but the problem is the text /Employee/Record does not exist as innerHTML or text written in the dom(this input also does not have a value attribute), the only way it can be obtained is through the `inputValue` function. 

When the code reaches 
`await this.page.waitForSelector('text="/Employee/Record"');` 

It times out well after the value has populated in the input

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use `expect()`, you should be able to get the text from an xPath selector.

Something like `this.page.waitForSelector('//*[@text="/Employee/Record"]');`

An input box would use `@value`, though:

`this.page.waitForSelector('//input[@value="/Employee/Record"]');`

Answer (score 1):

This will wait for the content of the span to include the string "some inner text".

```
while(await page.$eval('span.class', (el) => !el.textContent?.includes('some inner text')));
```

I suggest making it a function and adding a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

**For any text element**, you may use:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('your value', {timeout: 20000})
```

**For any element other than input** you can use:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveText(/Welcome, Test User/);
```

**These are [auto retrying](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#auto-retrying-assertions) assertions so they wait till element gets that value.**

> **Note**: As [toHaveText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text) can accept even an list of values along with retrying &  can regex as well , I found its one of the most  powerful & versatile assertion
> which can be used in lot of different scenarios effectively.